# Is there anything equivalent of np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided in tensorflow?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

Does anybody know what is the tensorflow's implementation of np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided method? When I simply include this numpy library the graph does not get created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in fact the documentation of [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) mentions:

> TensorFlow does not support strides, so `transpose` returns a new tensor with the items permuted.

So not only you cannot manipulate strides, but operations that are "free" in NumPy, like [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), become expensive in TensorFlow.

Comment: That's very unfortunate

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following 'tf.extract_image_patches' method, it may meet your needs.
refer to the tensorflow documentation for the usage method。